# Document model validation using ASP.NET Web API help page

Tags: documentation, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the ASP.NET Web Api Help Page package from Nuget to provide basic documentation of an API I'm developing. However, a common theme in my action declaration is the existence of a single "model" parameter, something like this:

```
public class UsersController
{
    public bool Post(UserUpdateModel model) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the web api help page that gets generated, a single parameter "model" is listed. I'd like to be able to document the properties of the model and validation requirements. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is currently not supported out of the box. There is an issue tracking it here. You can up-vote it:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/877

Comment: That Link is dead.